# Store SQL server varchar max in SSIS string

Tags: sql-server, ssis

What i am doing -

Get single row result set from `execute sql task` (EST) via `oledb connection` (OLE).

I want to set ssis variable strName = row's 1st column value (a varchar max). strName is a ssis string FOR SURE. I checked.

In EST - result name = 0, variable name = `User::strName`.

I get the error -

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to
>   variable "strName": "The type of the value being assigned to variable 
>   "User::strName" differs from the current variable type. Variables may 
>   not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except
>   for  variables of type Object.

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is SSIS doesn't understand varchar(max) as a data type .You need to specify the limit . CAST the varchar(max) column to varchar(8000) to solve the problem. Or you can store the VARCHAR max into a SSIS object and then get the value using object.ToString();

Answer (score 2):

Use an ADO.NET connection. OLEDB cannot cope with varchar(max).