# Assigning value from single row result set in ssis giving error in SSIS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to get CSV IDs from a table from sql server and assign the result to a variable. below is the sql I have put inside the **Execute SQL Task**

```sql
set nocount on
declare @csv varchar(max) = ''
select @csv = @csv + cast(companyid as varchar(10)) + ',' from company where isprocessed = 0
select substring(@csv,1,len(@csv) - 1) as companyids
```

As you can see its a simple and standard way of getting csv of a field in t-sql. It works perfectly in query window but throwing below error when I run the Task in SSIS 2012

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: The value type (__ComObject) can only be
>   converted to variables of type Object.
>
> [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to
>   variable "sCSVCompanyIds": "The type of the value (DBNull) being
>   assigned to variable "User::sCSVCompanyIds" differs from the current
>   variable type (String). Variables may not change type during
>   execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type
>   Object. ".

Below are the settings of Execute SQL Task

1. In **General** tab, Resultset project is set to **single row**
2. In **Result Set** tab, Result Name is set to 0 (I also tried by setting it to `csvids` which is the alias column name in the select list) and Variable Name is set to `User::sCSVCompanyIds`

I have no clue why its not working. After wasting so much time I am worked out a hard way which by returning the result as Full Row set (same SQL which returns 1 row 1 column always) and add a for each loop container to loop throw the result set (which will always iterates only once for obvious reasons) and assign the result set's fields to the variable. It works for me but there should be easy way of doing it. What I am missing?

Comment: try to add  AS in the select clause                                                                select... cast(id AS varchar(10)) + ',' from ...  when I run the code returns Error

Comment: @alex Thanks and please ignore that error. I have accidentally removed it when i changed actual table/columns. Corrected now

Comment: Did you set the DataType in the window Variables to String?

Comment: _The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User::sCSVCompanyIds" differs from the current variable type (String)_ implies that maybe nothing is returned (NULL) and it doesn't like it. Have you tried adding an `ISNULL` to your expression? I find assigning parameters and outputs to the execute task very limited and buggy.

Comment: try to assign a defualt value to the Variable in tab Value like "filename"

Comment: The companyid is primary key so, nulls are not expected. I have assigned default value 0,0 to the variable.

Comment: BTW: select NULL as companyid also assigned null value to the variable

Comment: I guess its the problem with varchar(max) datatype. may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009091/store-sql-server-varchar-max-in-ssis-string

Comment: thats the case. in my case I changed connection to ado.net. same thing working without any other change

Comment: If you can, please post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with the nvarchar(max) data type. I assume it will be same for varchar(max) also. Though relevant data types in SSIS are DT_NTEXT and DT_TEXT are present for some reason we are getting this error.

There are multiple options to handle this.

One Of course there might be more appropriate way to handle this by cast/converting the column within the query to fixed length instead of max something like cast(myvarcharmaxfield as varchar(8000)). In my case it doesn't work because I expect bigger length string. I am generating a csv string from a unique identifier column which itself is 36 chars long string and needs 3 extra chars for quoting them with signle quote and a comma as separator which will support only 205 values. So it doesn't work for me.

So I left with no option but to stick the way I implemented already which is in my question

> After wasting so much time I am worked out a hard way which by
>   returning the result as Full Row set (same SQL which returns 1 row 1
>   column always) and add a for each loop container to loop throw the
>   result set (which will always iterates only once for obvious reasons)
>   and assign the result set's fields to the variable

The new way I learnt is from an unaccepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009091/store-sql-server-varchar-max-in-ssis-string)

Change the Oledb connection to ADO.NET connection

I think this is fair enough but it requires me to create another connection manager (so that I don't have to change all existing tasks) and use it for this type of taks where I need csv but I did not buy it as I have very little time to doing research on creating connection string of it which appears to me with the type of erros I am getting is different from oledb.